# 6-8 weeks in Phineas and Ferb?

Tags: dialogue, reference, phineas-and-ferb

I was watching *Phineas and Ferb* S02. In the episode "[Phineas and Ferb Busters](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb-Busters!)" , I was surprised to find a dialogue.

At the Doofenshmirtz Evil Inc.,  Heinz Doofenshmirtz gets a package in a mail. [Norm](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Norm) receives it and says,

> You will be delighted if you get a package in ***6-8 weeks!***

I was startled after hearing the words 6-8 weeks because it is Stack Exchange's [infamous meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/357396) originated by Jeff Atwood. But its [earliest reference was from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190745/357396) *Muppet Babies*. *[Crazy Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog)* also has a reference of 6-8 weeks.

Now, I am interested to know from where the animators got the idea of using it because the season 2 was from 2010 which is after the starting of Stack Overflow and it became famous by then. Is it a coincidence that they might have been used Jeff's words?

From where did the animators get the idea to refer 6-8 weeks?  Is there any word from the animators?

Comment: You will get your answer in 6-8 weeks... :P

Comment: I love how this question now has between 6-8 upvotes.

Comment: Similar question on the mother meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog

Comment: @JMac Yes, I left a comment on Shadow's question on the day I posted this question. :)

Comment: I don't see the link between Atwood's comments about telling people it would be 6-8 weeks, and Norm's expression at being *delighted* at getting a *package* in 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 8):

Before the days of Amazon, when items were advertised for sale on the TV with a "call now! Our operators are standing by" number or on the back of a cereal box, typical shipping was 6-8 weeks.

Comment: https://genius.com/Smash-mouth-walkin-on-the-sun-lyrics

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Please expand to say why you think this is an inspiration to the animators/writers, and provide evidence if you can.

Comment: 8 upvotes stand to differ.

Comment: Upvotes do not confer veracity. The questions asks for comments from the shows creators...this is not that....it's just a guess.